# Trigger In managed package causing SOQL Limit Exception

Tags: trigger, managed-package, process-builder

We have a process builder on a object through which we are updating related parent contact field .When we try to update the field from the process builder a trigger is executed which is in managed package installed by Our client. Which is causing to exceed SOQL 101 limits .

P.S. : The recursive check is true in PB.

[image]
So, It is running multiple times.

Have anyone faced simier issue Or any work arounds?

Comment: I think you need to characterise this as "together, our process builder and a managed package trigger are exceeding the SOQL query limit". Three points: 1. Does your process builder have to be recursive? 2. Have you raised this with the managed package developers? 3. Are you aware that Process Builders need to be migrated to flows before the end of this year since they are being retired?

Comment: I would add few quesitons to the Phil's ones: Are there other Process Builder/Flow/Workflow Rules/Trigger on that object? Do the recursive Process Builder or the trigger in the managed package update other objects? If so, you should check automated processes on that objects too. Keep in mind that most likely the trigger in the managed package isn't the one to fix, the error just says where the last SOQL happens.

Comment: Yes Phil, I know PB will be migrated to flow but for now, we have to work PB . I would like to raising the issue to managed package developers lately because it is kind of time-consuming and this is something urgent .And as  RubenDG said I want to make sure that It is not from our side, and talking about the other process on the object ,yes there are other process also in here and I debuged them and I think because of running multiple processes there are a lot soqls are running which is causing error.